# ReactJS with Elasticsearch App Architecture

Tags: architecture, reactjs, elasticsearch

I want some advice regarding my architecture and hosting options.
I'm attempting to build an e-commerce site for e-books. It will use nestJS for the backend and ReactJS+Typescript for the frontend.
Postgresql will be the DB. I want to use Elasticsearch to provide search capabilities.

Initially, I thought to host each of these projects in their own server. But since I'll be using Elasticsearch for the portion most in need of scalability; I can put the front and back ends on the same server.
 Something akin to this: [image]

I would still need the backend as a separate project to perform user authentication and other utilities.

Does this make sense? Would a monolithic architecture work better in this case? I'm not serving multiple frontends nor would backend API be public. 
Maybe it will present an issue if I succeed with this and think of making a mobile app.

I was thinking of starting with the digital ocean as my hosting platform; I'd need three servers at minimum (DB, es, and front+back-ends).

I would love to read your insights.

Answer (score 0):

A microservice architecture is about which services can be independently built, tested and deployed. There is no requirement to host each microservice on it's own server. The difference is that you *could* host one on their own server whereas in a monolith, all services must be deployed together.

Draw your service boundaries along domain boundaries.

Comment: So one domain would be book related functions, another is user operations, and so on? I'm just not certain a microservice architecture applies as well in the way I laid out the web app.

Comment: Just because everyone is talking about microservices doesn't mean it's really the only thing that matters. Especially if you don't expect a monthly user growth of several thousand, it's perfectly ok to build the application as a monolith first and use Domain Driven Design there, for example, then it's easier to migrate to microservices later on.